# How to get parameters using the id of an element

Tags: c#, revit-api

Ok, right now I have an app where I click on an element and then a windows forms window shows the element properties. This is how it is now :

```
Reference reference = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection.ObjectType.Element);
Element element = doc.GetElement(reference);
Parameter length = element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.CURVE_ELEM_LENGTH);
Parameter height = element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.WALL_USER_HEIGHT_PARAM);
Parameter area = element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.HOST_AREA_COMPUTED);
var form1 = new Form1(
                (length.AsDouble().ToString(),
                height.AsDouble().ToString(),
                area.AsDouble().ToString(),
                doc);
```

Everything is working well, no problems! BUT, now, what I want is that instead of clicking on the element, I want to type the element id and get the parameters by the id of the element. In other words, I wouldnt be clicking on any element.

I tried commenting the reference (because I dont need it anymore) and passing the Id of the element as parameter for GetElement:

```
//Reference reference = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection.ObjectType.Element);
Element element = doc.GetElement("358425");
```

But it doesnt work. The element is null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is expected. Look at the documentation of the [`GetElement` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/8760be74-50fd-6809-aec6-3cb168d03ea5.htm). It takes three overloads. The one taking a string argument expects a unique id input. You are providing the string representation of the element id instead. That is a different thing. Interpreted as a unique id, it is invalid, so you receive a null element. You need to create an `ElementId` from your string (or integer number) using the [element id constructor taking an `int`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/3acc195c-36fa-4ec9-78e0-370a12fddda5.htm) and pass that to the appropriate `GetElement` overload..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
You cant type the element id directy, doesnt matter if its a string or an int. You have to create an Elementid object. Sometimes things are just more complicated than they need to be!

The solution:
Element element = doc.GetElement(new ElementId(Int32.Parse(inputText)));